# How to make a single background image that will show up on all the grid layouts (Java GUI)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, background-image, imageicon

My apologies if this has already been covered but all the other topics I filtered/saw are all about XAML and none about Java.

So I am trying to create a restaurant app and I am using GridBagLayout, GridBagConstraints, etc for my starting page. I am able to arrange the grids to my liking but the problem I am encountering is with the background-image. It is only permeating on one of the grids when I change the c.gridx and c.gridy values. The only solution I can find is that I need to insert different background images for each grid layout/Jpanel (I have 3 so far). Is there a way for me to use a single ImageIcon (or any method) that would show my background image on all the grids?

Thanks.

Here are my codes below:

```
package BeginnerAppPractice;

import java.util.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class StartPage extends JFrame {
    
    Container mainPanel;
        
    public StartPage() {
        super("The Dark Worlds");
        mainPanel = new Container();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        
        
        //For editing our grids
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); 
        
        //Title Pane content and settings
        JLabel titleContent = new JLabel("Restaurant Name", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Font fonttitle = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,60);
        titleContent.setForeground(Color.RED);
        titleContent.setFont(fonttitle);
        
        //Title Pane settings
        JPanel title = new JPanel();
        
        title.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        title.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        title.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        title.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        title.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        
        
        //Title Pane Grid Settings
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        mainPanel.add(title.add(titleContent), c);
        
       
        //For Portfolio
        JLabel optionsStartContent = new JLabel("Food Portfolio", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        Font fontoptionsStart = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,20);
        optionsStartContent.setForeground(Color.RED);
        optionsStartContent.setFont(fontoptionsStart);
        
        JPanel optionsStart = new JPanel();
        optionsStart.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        optionsStart.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        optionsStart.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        optionsStart.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsStart.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsStart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));
                
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        mainPanel.add(optionsStart.add(optionsStartContent), c);
        
        //For Exit
        JLabel optionsExitContent = new JLabel("Exit App", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        Font fontoptionsExit = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,20);
        optionsExitContent.setForeground(Color.RED);
        optionsExitContent.setFont(fontoptionsExit);
        
        JPanel optionsExit = new JPanel();
        optionsExit.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        optionsExit.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        optionsExit.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        optionsExit.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsExit.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsExit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));
                
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        mainPanel.add(optionsExit.add(optionsExitContent), c);
         
        //Background Image that would fill the container
        ImageIcon background=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\RoastedDuck.png");
        Image img=background.getImage();
        Image temp=img.getScaledInstance(600,200,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        background=new ImageIcon(temp);
        JLabel back=new JLabel(background);
        back.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        back.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 200);
        
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        mainPanel.add(back, c);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

and

```
package BeginnerAppPractice;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartPage startpage = new StartPage();
        startpage.add(startpage.mainPanel);
        startpage.pack();
        startpage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        startpage.setVisible(true);
        startpage.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        startpage.setResizable(true);
        
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks to this answer:

```
You could use your JLabel with the background image as your background panel and then just set a layout manager for the label, then add components to the label. Or you could do custom painting of a JPanel to paint the background image and then add your components to the panel. See: Background Panel for more information and a custom class you could use as the background panel. – camickr 4 hours ago
```

I realized that I should do this instead:

```
package BeginnerAppProject;

import java.util.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class StartPage extends JFrame {
    
    Container mainPanel;
        
    public StartPage() {
        super("The Dark Worlds Resto");
        mainPanel = new Container();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //For editing our grids
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); 
        
        //Background Image
        
        ImageIcon background=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\RoastedDuck.png");
        Image img=background.getImage();
        Image temp=img.getScaledInstance(600,400,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        background=new ImageIcon(temp);
        JLabel back=new JLabel(background);
        back.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        back.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        mainPanel.add(back, c);
       
        //Title Pane content and settings
        JLabel titleContent = new JLabel("Restaurant Name", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Font fonttitle = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,60);
        titleContent.setForeground(Color.RED);
        titleContent.setFont(fonttitle);
        
        //Title Pane settings
        JPanel title = new JPanel();
        
        title.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        title.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        title.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 4));
        title.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        title.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));
        
        //Title Pane Grid Settings
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        back.add(title.add(titleContent), c);
        
       //
        JLabel optionsStartContent = new JLabel("Food Portfolio", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        Font fontoptionsStart = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,20);
        optionsStartContent.setForeground(Color.RED);
        optionsStartContent.setFont(fontoptionsStart);
        
        JPanel optionsStart = new JPanel();
        optionsStart.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        optionsStart.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        optionsStart.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 4));
        optionsStart.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsStart.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsStart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = .5;
        c.weighty = .5;
        back.add(optionsStart.add(optionsStartContent), c);
        
        //
        JLabel optionsExitContent = new JLabel("Options", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        Font fontoptionsExit = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN,20);
        optionsExitContent.setForeground(Color.RED);
        optionsExitContent.setFont(fontoptionsExit);
        
        JPanel optionsExit = new JPanel();
        optionsExit.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
        optionsExit.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        optionsExit.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 4));
        optionsExit.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsExit.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        optionsExit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));
        
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.weightx = .5;
        c.weighty = .5;
        back.add(optionsExit.add(optionsExitContent), c);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

But when I was editing the code there were so many useless lines so I just simplified with this:

```
package BeginnerAppProject;

import java.util.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class StartPage extends JFrame {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    JLabel title, start, options, exit;
    JLabel spaces1, spaces2;
    JPanel container;
    GridBagConstraints c; 
        
    public StartPage() {
        
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        container = new JPanel();
        
        ImageIcon background=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\RoastedDuck.png");
        Image img=background.getImage();
        Image temp=img.getScaledInstance(600,400,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        background=new ImageIcon(temp);
        JLabel back=new JLabel(background);
        back.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
        back.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        container.add(back);
        
        //Space
            spaces1 = new JLabel("");
            back.add(spaces1);
            
        //Title Settings
        title = new JLabel("Restaurant Name", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        Font fonttitle = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,60);
        title.setForeground(Color.RED);
        title.setFont(fonttitle);
        
        back.add(title);
        
        //Space
        spaces2 = new JLabel("");
        back.add(spaces2);
        
        //Other Settings
        start = new JLabel("Food Portfolio", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        Font fontoptions = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.BOLD,15);
        start.setForeground(Color.RED);
        start.setFont(fontoptions);
        
        back.add(start);
        
        //Other Settings
        options = new JLabel("Bookings, Schedules, and Others", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        options.setForeground(Color.RED);
        options.setFont(fontoptions);
        
        back.add(options);
        
        //Other Settings
        exit = new JLabel("Exit", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        exit.setForeground(Color.RED);
        exit.setFont(fontoptions);
        
        back.add(exit);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Swing has a parent / child relationship. So you have a parent panel and you add child components to the panel. So you would have a JFrame -> background panel -> child components.  *It is only permeating on one of the grids* - Swing component (except JLabel) are opaque by default, so you won't see the background when you add a JButton to the background panel unless you use `setOpaque(false)` on the button.

Comment: You could use your JLabel with the background image as your background panel and then just set a layout manager for the label, then add components to the label. Or you could do custom painting of a JPanel to paint the background image and then add your components to the panel. See: [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for more information and a custom class you could use as the background panel.

Comment: "You could use your JLabel with the background image as your background panel and then just set a layout manager for the label, then add components to the label." - I tried it and it worked. I moved my background image codes at the very top and added all other components to it. Thank you so much. =)

Comment: Consider to add a self answer then with some code examples.